# How to get each array obj as a string with within quotes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array

```
var arr = ["2/3", "3/4", "4/5"];
```

I need a string like: `"2/3", "3/4", "4/5"`

I tried `arr.toString()` and `arr.join(", ")` But if I do `console.log(arr)` get `2/3, 3/4, 4/5`

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

What i am trying to do is to print a series of dates into chart.js xAxis

```
data: {
    labels: [arr],
```

If I try to manually set `labels: ["2/3", "3/4", "4/5"],` it's fine

This is my literal console.log of my array:

```
4) ["3/13/20", "3/14/20", "3/15/20", "3/16/20"]
0: "3/13/20"
1: "3/14/20"
2: "3/15/20"
3: "3/16/20"
```

**FULL CODE:**

```js
var months = ["gennaio", "febbraio", "marzo", "aprile", "maggio", "giugno", "luglio", "agosto", "settembre", "ottobre", "novembre", "dicembre"];
var datesA = ["3/13/20", "3/14/20", "3/15/20", "3/16/20"];

var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [datesA],
    datasets: [{
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(109, 33, 50, 1)",
      data: [

      ],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      fontSize: 18,
      fontStyle: 'normal',
      display: true
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          callback: function(value) {
            return Number(value).toLocaleString();
          }
        }
      }]
    },
    elements: {
      line: {
        tension: 0,
        fill: false
      }
    }
  }
};

window.onload = function() {
  var ctxAll = document.getElementById('allDates').getContext('2d');
  window.myLine = new Chart(ctxAll, config);
};
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id='allDates'/>
```

Comment: And where do you want these value? These are already string values. If you are printing it on DOM, the you'll have to add quotes

Comment: I just need to get them, a console.log would be fine or set them as a var

Comment: you can use var text =  JSON.stringify(arr); https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

Comment: *But I get 2/3, 3/4, 4/5* where was this?

Comment: @Rajesh updated the question, basically I do `console.log(arr)`

Comment: You can try it this way: `arr.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item)
})`

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(arr).replace("[","").replace("]",""));

Comment: a string with a value `"2/3"` is written as `'"2/3"'`. Maybe you are looking for `var arr = ['"2/3"', '"3/4"', '"4/5"']; ` ?

Comment: @KentaNomoto updated the question to better put it in context

Comment: @PrikeshSavla updated the question to better put it in context

Comment: @SMAKSS tried it but it places all values on the left of the aXis

Comment: Why dont you try ? data: {  labels: arr, } or maybe you need the spread operator - 
console.log({data: {label: [...arr]}});

Comment: @PrikeshSavla of course I tried just to place the array in it, but it stuck all the dates on the left

Comment: Please add a demo in your code to show the issue, as it is creating lots of confusion here.

Comment: @palaѕн i just placed the whole code in the updated question

Comment: I'm basically trying to create this but with my data https://michelemottini.github.io/Covita/

Comment: Still confusion. What is `datesA` and `allDates` here?

Comment: @palaѕн `allDates` is the canvas ID, `datesA` is my `array` set of dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be

```js
var arr = ["2/3", "3/4", "4/5"];

var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: arr,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My First dataset',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<canvas id='chart'/>
```

According to your edit:

I'm going to assume `datesA` is an array and has values like the following. If so, the only problem is you were using `[datesA]` instead of `datesA`, effectively passing an array with a single item which was an array as well, that's why all your dates were showing *stacked* to the left

```js
var datesA = ["2/3", "3/3", "4/3"];
 var months = ["gennaio", "febbraio", "marzo", "aprile", "maggio", "giugno", "luglio", "agosto", "settembre", "ottobre", "novembre", "dicembre"];
        var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: datesA,
            datasets: [{
                fill: false,
                backgroundColor: "rgba(109, 33, 50, 1)",
                data: [

                ],
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title: {
                fontSize: 18,
                fontStyle: 'normal',
                display: true
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false
            },
            hover: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: true
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        callback: function (value) {
                            return Number(value).toLocaleString();
                        }
                    }
                }]
            },
            elements: {
                line: {
                    tension: 0,
                    fill: false
                }
            }
        }
    };
    window.onload = function() {
        var ctxAll = document.getElementById('allDates').getContext('2d');
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctxAll, config);
    };
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<canvas id='allDates'></canvas>
```

Comment: I did try to set it like that but it places all my dates on the stacked on the left

Comment: @rob.m well, I think you are gonna have to share some more code or a snippet somewhere to visualize the problem. also what do you mean by *on the stacked on the left*?

Comment: Just updated the question with the log of my array, what i tried is simply to put that array name within label but nothing, it stacks all on the left side

Comment: i just placed the whole code in the updated question

Comment: No way!!! `labels: datesA,` hahah Thanks a lot, totally missed it!

Comment: @rob.m final guess: is it bed time where you are right now? been there, tiredom plays us all ;)

Comment: had to do the whole night indeed, it's 7:30am but haven't slept yet, had to push this out for the morning and this bit is just a little part of a much bigger thing. Thanks a lot

Comment: @rob.m: Just curious. Someone in main post comment had mentioned the same thing like "_Why dont you try ? data: { labels: arr, }_" but you had replied.. "_of course I tried just to place the array in it, but it stuck all the dates on the left_" ?!?!

Comment: @palaѕн i think I've mix confused the comments, i was actually trying to apply the suggestions while commenti. Surely my fault

Comment: @palaѕн **7:30am**, c'mon let's give the guy a break :)

Comment: oh ok. No probs. happens most of the time when we do night hackathons :-)

Comment: grazie! Thanks you very much, pushing and off to bed :)

Comment: Remember, health is more important than anything and good sleep of 7-8 hrs is very important for giving the time to mind to refresh.

Comment: @rob.m also maybe it's not the place for this but, stay strong against CV, it's a problem that affects us all, coders and muggles

Comment: @palaѕн yes indeed, then you become a founder of a startup and you forget about what's important...

Comment: yes thanks @Scaramouche tbh we're about to put out a version of our product to track covid-19, that's why long nights....

Comment: I like this [bing covid](https://www.bing.com/covid) site and this [simple one](https://cutting.scot/covid-19) also.

Comment: @palaѕн yes I've seen them, nice